# inverse of Laplacian acting on the convolution?

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, convolution

Let us think of the Hilbert space
\begin{equation}
H:=\Bigl( f \in L^2[0,1] \mid \int_0^1 f(x) dx=0 \Bigr)
\end{equation}
that is, the space of $L^2$ functions without the zero mode.

On $H$, I am aware that the inverse of the Laplacian $(-\Delta)^{-1}$ can be defined as a bounded linear map. In fact, $(-\Delta)^{-1}$ maps $H$ into the Sobolev space $H^2[0,1]$.

Now, for any $f, g \in H$, let us denote by $f*g$ their convolution:
\begin{equation}
(f*g)(x)=\int_0^1 f(x-y)g(y)dy
\end{equation}

It is clear from Fourier transform that $f*g \in H$ as well.

My question is that, the following manipulation is correct?:
\begin{equation}
(-\Delta)^{-1}(f*g)=\Bigl[(-\Delta)^{-1}f \Bigr] * g = f* \Bigl[(-\Delta)^{-1} g\Bigr]
\end{equation}

I mimicked the property of differential operation on convolution but not sure if this is really true.. Could anyone please help me?

Comment: Hint: What happens when you take the Fourier transforms of your expressions? (Which, incidentally, is how most sources define inverse and fractional differentiation operators anyway). Alternatively, convolution is commutative.

Comment: Oh, all terms lead to the same expression. I see. Thank you.